# How to hide other div's except the required one?

Tags: jquery

I have a got HTML as shown below

```
<div class="inner-accordion">
   <div id="activeui4" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="4">
         <section id="topping_tsection_4">
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="activeui5" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="5">
         <section id="topping_tsection_5">
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="activeui6" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On click of a button , i am calling a function  to which i will be passing the id .

```
function showToppers(id)
{
var id  =4 ;
$('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details").toggle();
}
```

My requirement is that how can i hide/block  all the other class Topping-details except the for id 4 in this case ??

Comment: Why would you pass `id` to the function and then **declare** id and assign it a value in the function? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply hide ALL of them then show the one you want:

```
function showToppers(id){
    $(".Topping-details").hide();//hide all of them 
    $('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details").show();//show the one you want
}
```

**UPDATED VERSION** to address OP's comment about how to close the open one.

```
function showToppers(id){
    $(".Topping-details").not("#"+id).hide();//hide all of them but the target one
    var $theoneiwant = $('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details");//store the target in a variable for efficiency
    if($theoneiwant.is(":visible")){//if it is open,
        $theoneiwant.hide();//close it
    } else {//its closed
        $theoneiwant.show();//open it
    }
}
```

Comment: And if that has been clicked on again , how can i hide that ?? so taht is the reason i went for toggle initially .

Answer (score 8):

Try this : Use `.not()` to filter topping-details with `id=4`

```
$('.Topping-details').not('#4').hide();
```

Comment: You're neglecting to consider the next line: `$('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details").toggle();` which TOGGLES the visibility. So imagine #3 is open and the other are closed. Then you click to open #4 and #1-3 are hidden but #4 is toggled closed (Thus nothing is open!)

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery:not()` selector

```
$('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details:not('#4')").hide();
```

Comment: I have tried using $('#activeui'+id+'.activateUiHTML').find(".Topping-details:not('#"+id+")").toggle();    , but i am getting unexpected String in console .

Comment: check your mix of apostrophes and quotes

Comment: Be careful with toggle. Imagine #4 is open and the others are closed. You then click to open #3 and this statement will close #4, open #1 and #2 and do nothing to #3.

Comment: @Moob yes you are correct and I updated my answer with hide() method

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dadg2tkn/)

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dadg2tkn/1/) ... using jQuery.toggleClick plugin to toggle on `n` clicks.

I would recommend using non-numeric ids, and instead of hard-coding the id in the function, you can use a `data` attribute to hold the target id in the `button`.

**HTML**

```
<button class="hider" data-hide-id="i4">Just i4</button>
<button class="hider" data-hide-id="i5">Just i5</button>
<button class="hider" data-hide-id="i6">Just i6</button>
<div class="inner-accordion">
   <div id="activeui4" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="i4">
         <section id="topping_tsection_4">
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="activeui5" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="i5">
         <section id="topping_tsection_5">
         </section>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="activeui6" class="activateUiHTML" data-role="collapsible">
      <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="i6"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('.hider').on('click',function() {
        var id = $(this).data('hide-id');
        $('.Topping-details').show().not('#' + id).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your effort . The fiddle is nice , but could you please tell me , how to toggle the content if it is licked on twice ??

Comment: And toggle again when clicked the third time ... ? There's a `toggleClick` plugin you can use for that where you would pass two functions ... a demo in a moment. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dadg2tkn/1/)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion , i mean that if clicked on JustI4 button , it is showing I4 content know , and when clicked on JustI4 button  again the content of I4 must get hide (Toggle functionality for content )

Comment: And would the rest (i5 & i6) remain hidden when i4 gets hidden? ... [**Like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/dadg2tkn/2/)

Comment: Sorry for the late response , this works excellent , thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".activateUiHTML").removeClass("active");
$("#activeui" + id).addClass("active");
```

Where the class active will have a

```
.activateUiHTML.active{
    display: block;
}
```

And normally it has

```
.activateUiHTML{
    display:none;
}
```

Doing it with CSS is much cleaner and works better on older/slower devices

Answer (score 0):

```
function hideSection(idToHide){
$(".Topping-details").each(function(){
    if(this.id == idToHide) {
        $(this).show();
    }else{
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
});
}
```

Call this function in button click..